# Why is MySQL matching strings and integers in a way I don't expect?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with the following column:

```
    +-----+
    | vpn |
    +-----+
    | 11a |
```

When I use query:

```
SELECT vpn FROM vpn_map  WHERE vpn=11;
```

It returns:

```
    +-----+
    | vpn |
    +-----+
    | 11a |
```

But if I query:

```
Select VPN from vpn_map where vpn=lla;
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '11a' in 'where clause'
```

Why doesn't the previous query match?  It will match if I do:

```
Select VPN from vpn_map where vpn='lla';
```

But then vpn='11' won't match anything.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent MySql from mangling queries by casting string to int](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89760/5203)

Comment: What you're missing is when you use 11 the system is implicitly casting the 11a to a signed value which truncates the Alphabetic values I think.  if vpn is of type varchar in the database then you'd have to use `like '11*'` to get all values starting with 11.

Comment: What is the data type of `vpn` column?

Comment: Because your expectations are off

Comment: @ Allen King it's a varchar.

Answer (score 1):

`11a` is not an integer and you have so use `"` around them otherwise you get an error.

```
SELECT vpn FROM vpn_map WHERE vpn="lla";
```

Comment: @ Stony, if I put quotes (single or double) it will not match the number only.

Comment: Actually you don't get an error.  that's what worried me the cast to signed it's doing implicity is dropping the alphabetic characters instead of tossing an error!  http://rextester.com/RDL18680  the implicit cast to signed is dropping the alphabetic.